# Find a necessary and sufficient condition for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x^{a_i}$ such that it can de divided by $x^2+x+1$.

Tags: polynomials

> Suppose $a_i\,(1\leq i\leq n)$ are non-negative integers. Find a necessary and sufficient condition for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x^{a_i}$ such that it can de divided by $x^2+x+1$.

\begin{align}
&(x^2+x+1)(b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_1x+b_0)\\[.2cm]
=&b_nx^{n+1}+(b_{n}+b_{n-1})x^{n+1}+(b_n+b_{n-1}+b_{n-2})x^{n}\\[.2cm]
&+\cdots+(b_2+b_1+b_0)x^2+(b_1+b_0)x+b_0
\end{align}
But I don't know how to use this relation.

Comment: $a_{i}$ is ambigious...What is $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}....$. Could you give an example?

Comment: An equal number of $a_i$ have each residue $\bmod 3$ is certainly sufficient.

Comment: The roots of $x^2+x+1$ are the two non-trivial $3$rd roots of unity. Just check whether those two roots are roots of the polynomial of choice.

Comment: Hint in a related direction: $x^2+x+1$ divides $\sum_i x^{a_i}$ if and only if $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ divides $(x-1)\sum_ix^{a_i}$. Can you see how to write the two products, and can you see how to do this divisibility test?

Answer (score 1):

I'll generalize your question a bit. Let $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ be real numbers. Then, I claim that the polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$ iff the sums $$S_0=a_0+a_3+a_6+\ldots,$$ $$S_1=a_1+a_4+a_7+\ldots,$$ $$S_2=a_2+a_5+a_8+\ldots$$ are all equal.

To prove this, let $\omega=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$, so that $\omega$ and $\overline{\omega}$ are precisely the roots of $x^2+x+1$. $P(x)$ will then be divisible by $x^2+x+1$ iff it also has these two complex numbers as roots. Since $P(\overline{\omega})=\overline{P(\omega)}$, we only need to check when $P(\omega)=0$.

Recalling that $\omega^3=1$, and combining like terms, we have that $$P(\omega)=S_0+S_1\omega+S_2\omega^2.$$ Since also, $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, our initial condition is equivalent to $$(S_1-S_0)+(S_2-S_0)\omega=0.$$ By comparing the imaginary components of both sides, we conclude that $S_2=S_0$, and therefore, that $S_1=S_0$. This was precisely our original claim.